# How to get profile image of logged user in suitescript 2.0 in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am able to get logged user details through below suitescript 2.0

```
    runtime.getCurrentUser();
```

The response is

```
{
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "ABC",
    "email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "location": 0,
    "department": 0,
    "role": 3,
    "roleId": "administrator",
    "roleCenter": "BASIC",
    "subsidiary": 1,
    "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta"
}
```

There is no property to get image from response of **getCurrentUser()**. 
Any other way to get profile picture of logged user in Suitescript 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to get the image id from the employee (user) record using the record or search module, passing in the user id:

```
var userId = runtime.getCurrentUser().id;
var userRecord = record.load({  //make sure 'N/record' is defined as record
    type: record.Type.EMPLOYEE,
    id: userId
});
var imageId = userRecord.getValue('image');
```

Or:

```
var userId = runtime.getCurrentUser().id;
var imageId = search.lookupFields({
    type: search.Type.EMPLOYEE,
    id: userId,
    columns: 'image'
}).image[0].value;
```

For server scripts, you can then use the `N/file` module to load the image file, passing in the `imageId`.  If you need to get the image in the client side, you can get the text of the field instead of the value:

```
var userId = runtime.getCurrentUser().id;
var imageId = search.lookupFields({
    type: search.Type.EMPLOYEE,
    id: userId,
    columns: 'image'
}).image[0].text;
```

which will return the relative path to the image in the file cabinet.